# How to make my new posted notes to be automatically shared on Facebook

Tags: facebook, evernote

I want to share every note of mine on Facebook—like the way wordpress.com works for us. Is there a similar feature in Evernote?

Answer (score 3):

Does Evernote provide an RSS feed of your notes? You can set up Facebook to [import notes](http://www.facebook.com/editnotes.php?import) from a blog or other RSS source.

[image: Import Notes]

Comment: Nice suggestion. I tried but cannot get it done.
My rss on evernote http://www.evernote.com/shard/s37/pub/3993783/vgnam2404/namgivu/rss.jsp?max=25&sort=2&search=

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this, although the method isn't quite obvious. Here's the *short version*:

1. ***Create an account on Postach.io***, the Evernote partner that allows you to post your blog directly from Evernote.
2. ***Configure it to capture all your notes*** (or whichever you'd like to be published) - very easy.
3. ***Enable the Postach.io RSS feed*** for your blog.
4. ***Use IFTTT to grab the RSS feed*** from that blog and post it to your desired Facebook account.
5. ***Post to your heart's content*** in Evernote!

While it seems a bit convoluted, I've been very pleased with how easy it is to do. Several friends wanted to do the same thing. Since they weren't tech oriented, I was worried about their ability to do this successfully without handholding. Fortunately, once they had each of the proper accounts set up, the rest was a piece of cake. There are also several good tutorials that are much more in-depth than what I can describe here in the space allowed.

I've used this successfully to publish to a hidden group my extended family has on Facebook, with great success. Good luck!